# jest - Connected component not generated in snapshot when nested in React SFC component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I have a SFC component. Recently I have a feature to add, and the easiest way to do it is to nest my connected component in this SFC(Stateless Functional Component) component.

I can have the app run ok, but the snapshot test failed because the connected component is not generated in the snapshot.

log:

```
- Snapshot
+ Received
@@ -95,10 +95,12 @@
         >
+
+          <Connect(SomeComponent) />
         </NavLink>
       </div>
     </li>
   </ol>
 </div>
```

SomeComponent:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component<IStateProps> {
  public render() {// render code}

function mapStateToProps(state: IRootState): IStateProps {
  return {// code}

export default connect<IStateProps>(mapStateToProps)(SomeComponent);
```

I'm pretty new to React. I'm not sure nesting a stateful component in a SFC makes sense, but doing this way does work. It's just the testing is failing.

So my question is

- Is it a good practice to nest a stateful component in a SFC component? If not, what should be a better way?
- If it is ok to do it this way, how to do snapshot test?

Comment: you use `shallow()`, don't you?

Comment: @skyboyer I'm using [ShallowRenderer](https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-renderer.html)

Comment: it's expected, that is how [shallow rendering works](https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-renderer.html). so either use full rendering or deal with that(and test your component separately). I believe later option is better.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are wrapping your component in connect, its like a new component for jest. you need to update your snapshot.

Comment: I updated the snapshot, but the component is not presented.

Comment: Do you mean you can't see your `SomeComponent` in the snapshot? the above snapshot is for the parent component of `SomeComponent`. you might want to capture separate snapshot as a test for `SomeComponent`.

Comment: Yeah I didn't see anything related to `SomeComponent`. So I only exported the connected component, not exporting the underlying presentational component. The test failed because the snapshot didn't contain "`<Connect(SomeComponent) />`" but the received value did. I don't know why the snapshot didn't contain either the connected component nor even some thing like `<SomeComponent>`. Shouldn't the snapshot reflect the code change? If the snapshot didn't have the element after it been updated, doesn't that mean the element is missing?